# asp mvc controller create html dynamically and sent to html

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using mustache template. I want to get HTML code dynamically form controller to html 
code and  I need to store it in a list then i want to move that html file.
in model. i have get list of htmlstring from controller. how to use generic list here

```
public List<HtmlString> imagelist { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
var c =new PropertyImageList();
foreach(var i in images)
    {
        var a = GetImageUrl(i);
        var b = GetThumbnailUrl(i);
        a= new HtmlString("<a href"+a+"></a>");
    }
    return Json(c,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: What does or doesn't this code do and what is your question? I'd try changing the `var c =` line to `var c =new List<HtmlString>();` and calling `c.Add(a)` in your loop. It does seem like you're doing something unordinary though, are you sure you want to convert a list of HTML to JSON?

Comment: propertyimagelist() class. from that class i will write to html.where images in foreach has collection of images.in Propertyimagelist class i created list. i need to call that class list in foreach and am sure i want to convert html to json.

Comment: in that class i want to create list'public List<PropertyImageList> imagecontainer(PropertyImageList url,PropertyImageList thumbnaiurl)
       {    
           ("here i need to get the value from for each")
       }'

Comment: in foreach instead of this " a= new HtmlString("<a href"+a+"></a>"); "

Comment: i want to call that function and then assign to that object c